# Tried Ubuntu Live; now cannot boot Windows 7?

Tags: 12.04, boot, windows

Earlier today, I placed an Ubuntu 12.04 disk in my computer to boot into Ubuntu Live.  I pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get into the boot order setup and chose to boot from the CD-Rom.  Everything went smoothly and I used Live for a while.

I went to power down the computer and ejected the disk and pressed Enter when it said to, shutting down without a problem.  However, when I turned the computer back on to boot Windows 7, nothing comes up except for a small blinking cursor in the upper left corner, and it just sits there.

How can I fix this?

Note:

Before I put the 12.04 disk in, I was going to try 6.10, so I put that disk in.  That disk had been included with a library book I had rented about Linux, so it had been used previously.

When it was loading, I decided to eject the disk and try 12.04 instead; mainly because I wasn't sure whether it was installing or just booting into Live.  I was pretty sure that I had selected to try it, not install it, but a loading screen sat there for a while, so I ejected it before it finished because I didn't want anything installed.

After ejecting and powering down, I booted Windows to be sure it worked, and it came up just fine.  The problems arose after trying Ubuntu 12.04 Live.  I'm thinking it might be video card problem, but I'm not sure.  A test said that the hard-drive was working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

use your windows install disk and try these commands   `bootrec /fixmbr`  if it didn't work then `bootrec /fixboot`  or simply use the startup repair